# docker: watch container logs/stdout/stderr from another container?

Tags: docker

I am writing a test framework that runs in a docker container and tests other containers.

One of the features I'd like to implement is the ability from my test framework container to perform an action against a target container (http post for ex) and watch the logs of the target container for a pattern.

I don't want to have to modify the target container to do this.

Is there a way to monitor the docker logs from one container to another?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount `/var/run/docker.sock` into your test container and then use Docker API which will use that socket. There is API endpoint, where you can read stdout/stderr logs of any container:

`GET /containers/(id or name)/logs`

> Get stdout and stderr logs from the container id

Doc: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/#get-container-logs

Comment: Remember that your container now has unrestricted root access over the host and can easily start and stop other containers, change the host’s root password, ...